# Creating a web service as a product. Technical advice needed

Tags: php, google-app-engine

I've been working on a school scheduling web app on `GAE` using `PHP` and I'm now looking into scaling it up having users sign up for the service.

The service it self allows people to manage a set of users and lessons on a schedule. These are then stored in an SQL DB with the necessary tables.

I'm looking for advice on how to scale this up so that users can sign up for the service and then have a version of the app created for them to use. For example, using a subdomain like `usersname.appurl.com`, where it would the a clean install of the app for them to use.

Any advice, links to reading, forum links, videos, etc would be greatly appreciated. Thanks a lot!

Comment: is it the same app with vanity URLs, or the same code deployed to different applications?

Comment: I'd like it to be the same code, but with the tables populated differently passed on the user. Would deploying a separate app be the best way to accomplish that? How would automation for that work?

Comment: still not clear what you want to do - having one app per user certainly doesn't scale. you can use wildcard subdomains to have fred.myappp.com and bill.myapp.com both running on the same app and you have code to work out the subdomain and then use the right data.

Comment: Take for example a service like Zendesk. I want to scale like that. Subdomains for each account. Each account has access to the app which is populated with their data.